# Accessing Memory in C and Pointer Arithmetic confusion

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am completely confused at something that is happening in my code, and I am not understanding why.

I have a buffer of memory that is coming from some hardware to me.  And I want to offset myself into the memory by laying a struct over top of the memory so I can simply access the struct.  But some of the data is simply a header of integer so I am doing the following:

If I do the following, where raw data is a void *, and its where the data is coming in:

```
uint32_t * data = (uint32_t * ) raw_data;
```

If I try to access this by *data I get garbage value.

Now if I define a struct like below:

```
typedef struct incoming_data __attribute__((__packed__))
{
   uint32_t dat;
} incoming_data
```

And access it with:

```
incoming_data * data = (incoming_data *) raw_data;
```

Then access it via data->dat I get the right value!

I checked that the address that the above two pointers are the same.  Can someone shed some light into what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you do both approaches (one after the other), does the uint32_t pointer approach still return a wrong value?

Comment: Your two examples are reading the `uint32_t` value from the same byte offset within the `raw_data` buffer, they are simply reaching that offset in different ways. The first example should not be returning garbage, unless `raw_data` points at garbage to begin with. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: Note that this could be a side effect of undefined behaviour in some other part of your code. But a MCVE like Remy wrote would help a lot.